# Converting BNF to EBNF - Parentheses without recursion?

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I need to convert the following grammar to EBNF:

```
<assign> -> <id> = <expr>
<id> -> A|B|C
<expr> -> <expr> + <expr>
    |<expr> * <expr>
    |<expr> * <expr>
    |( <expr> )
    |<id>
```

The progress I've currently made is below:

```
<assign> -> <id> = <expr>
<id> = (A | B | C)
<expr> -> <id> {(+ | * ) <expr>} | ‘(‘ <expr> ‘)’
```

Is it best to eliminate all recursion if using EBNF? Is there even a way to accomplish it using only `<id>` in `<expr>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<assign> -> <id> = <expr>
<expr>   -> <mul>  {+ <mul>}
<mul>    -> <term> {* <term>}
<term>   -> ( <expr> ) | <id>
<id>     -> A | B | C
```

No left recursion, and `*` takes precedence over `+`, but not over `( ... )`.

Comment: Ah, didn't think to add other non-terminals. Thanks!